# Kendo Validator Displays Wrong Default Message for ComboBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

The messages within the INPUT ELEMENTS are populated correctly from data annotations, but the KendoValidator seems to be creating something different.

- **Q: Why is this happening?**
- **Q: How do I fix it?** - I am open to updating through JavaScript

To keep it simple, lets just look at ONE of the drop-downs...

**HTML:**
Notice how `data-val-required` contains the actual correct message?

```
<span class="k-widget k-combobox k-header" style="width: 100%;">
    <span tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default input-validation-error">
        <input name="Entity.DeviceTypeId_input" class="k-input k-valid" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" placeholder="Select Device Type..." tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-owns="Entity_DeviceTypeId_listbox" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="bec66a14-dad2-4632-84ba-02a9e3b5a10d" style="width: 100%;">
        <span tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" class="k-select">
            <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" role="button" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="Entity_DeviceTypeId_listbox">select</span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DeviceTypeId must be a number." data-val-required="Device Type is required." id="Entity_DeviceTypeId" name="Entity.DeviceTypeId" required="required" style="width: 100%; display: none;" type="text" aria-required="true" data-role="combobox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-invalid="true" class="k-invalid">
</span>
```

**DATA ANNOTATION:**
As you can see, the message in `data-val-required` is correct...

```
public class DeviceAnnotations
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Device Type is required.")]
    public object DeviceTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required.")]
    public object StateId { get; set; }
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**
I am open to updating the JavaScript, but I would rather understand WHY & WHERE wrong messages come from...

```
var validationRoutine = {
    validate: function (e) {

        var comboBoxes = $(".k-combobox");

        $.each(comboBoxes, function (key, value) {

            var $input = $(value).find("input.k-invalid");    //<-- this is where Kendo foolishly places k-invalid
            var $span = $(this).find("span.k-dropdown-wrap"); //<-- this span controls the dropdown's appearance.

            if ($input.length > 0) { // k-invalid exists...
                $span.addClass("input-validation-error");
                return;
            }

            $span.removeClass("input-validation-error");
        });
    }
};

$('form').kendoValidator(validationRoutine);
```

**SCREEN SHOT:**
[image]

Comment: can you try `$("form").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator").validate()` without any routine? Is this proper?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about this, but it happens because you have `required` attribute and it is showing the error message based on your `name="Entity.DeviceTypeId"` that is

> Entity DeviceTypeId is required

Can you please try by adding

```
validationMessage="Device Type is required."
```

to your `input`.

I think this should work, I have used it but not in `asp`

Comment: This didn't work.  And, it kinda makes sense that it doesn't because then there would be no sense in having a "messages" collection in the "validation-initializer"  OPTIONS.  Thanks for the help

Comment: This worked for me in .NET 7 using the latest version of Telerik UI for ASP.NET Core,